# Polymer Elements - Smarter responsive solution

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, polymer-starter-kit

I'm currently using following code in Polymer 1.0 to make a part of my web page responsive (it works):

```
<template is="dom-bind">
   <iron-media-query query="(max-width: 750px)" query-matches="{%raw%}{{isLarge}}{%endraw%}"></iron-media-query>
   <!-- set an attribute if isLarge is true -->
     <div large$="{%raw%}{{!isLarge}}{%endraw%}">
       <div class="layout vertical">
       {{ content }}
       </div>
     </div>
     <div large$="{%raw%}{{isLarge}}{%endraw%}">
       <div class="layout horizontal">
       {{ content }}
       </div>
     </div>
</template>
```

In my css I have

```
[wide] {
      display: none;
    }
```

To hide the `<div>` if false.

Now, I wonder if there's a smarter way to solve this without the double `<div>`.

- Can I put the condition into the "class=" somehow?
- Would something like [@apply(--layout-horizontal)](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout) in the css work better?

**Note**
I noticed that in Polymer 0.5 `<div layout vertical>` works but not in Polymer 1.0. Instead, only `<div class="layout vertical">` seems to work for Polymer 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

### Computing the class

In your particular case, the content seems to remain the same, and the only difference is the horizontal/vertical class. Fortunately you can use computed values for this! Here's a sample:

```
<div large$="{%raw%}{{!isLarge}}{%endraw%}">
   <div class$="_computeThisClass(isLarge)">
      {{ content }}
   </div>
</div>

...

Polymer({
   ...
   _computeThisClass: function(isLarge) {
      if(isLarge) {
         return "layout horizontal";
      } else {
         return "layout vertical";
      }
   }
}
```

For me, the downside of this last one is that you (AFAIK) need to include all the classes you need to apply in the js.

### Using the `hidden`-attribute

If you just want to hide elements, I suggest using the `hidden` attribute. This can take a boolean or a computed value, as mentioned [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#expressions-in-binding-annotations). An example:

```
<div large$="{%raw%}{{!isLarge}}{%endraw%}" hidden$="{{!isLarge}}">
   <div class="layout vertical">
      {{ content }}
   </div>
</div>
```

The downside is that the content does get stamped onto the page (this is essentially applying a conditional `display: none;`).

### Using conditional templates

There is also the option to to this using a [conditional template](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-if). An example:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{!isLarge}}">
    <div large$="{%raw%}{{!isLarge}}{%endraw%}">
       <div class="layout vertical">
          {{ content }}
       </div>
    </div>
<template>
```

The downside is that content gets stamped on the page at a later stage (when the condition is met), which can cause delays. But good when the condition is unlikely to change!

In your case simply computing the class would I believe be the best.